# MySQL Select Not Returning resource

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am having a small problem with my PHP MySQL Select. The function is inside of a PHP class. Here is the error I get:

> Warning:  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   integer given in C:\xampp\htdocs\include\database.php on line 59
>   Warning:  extract() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\include\database.php on line 59

The function just simply updates the database to show what browser and OS they visited the site with. The function is called from another file that is called by an AJAX call that uses POST to send the data about the OS and browser that was gathered from a Javascript file. It only fails if there is an entry of the IP address already in the database. If there is no IP Address entry in the database it succeeds in creating one.

Here is my code:

```
function addStat($browser, $os){
    $IE = 0; $Firefox = 0; $Safari = 0; $Opera = 0; $Chrome = 0; $otherb = 0;
    $Windows = 0; $Linux = 0; $Mac = 0; $Android = 0; $iOS = 0; $otheros = 0;
    $ql = 0; $totalVisits = 0;
    $ip = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $q1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_STATS . " WHERE ip='$ip'", $this->connection);
    if (mysql_num_rows($q1)==0){
        $browser = mysql_real_escape_string($browser);
        $os = mysql_real_escape_string($os);
        switch($browser){
            case "Internet Explorer":
                $IE += 1;
            break;
            case "Firefox":
                $Firefox += 1;
            break;
            case "Safari":
                $Safari += 1;
            break;
            case "Opera":
                $Opera += 1;
            break;
            case "Chrome":
                $Chrome += 1;
            break;
            default:
                $otherb += 1;
            break;
        }
        switch($os){
            case "Windows":
                $Windows += 1;
            break;
            case "Mac OS X":
                $Mac += 1;
            break;
            case "Linux":
                $Linux += 1;
            break;
            case "Android":
                $Android += 1;
            break;
            case "iOS":
                $iOS += 1;
            break;
            default:
                $otheros += 1;
            break;
        }
        $q = $this->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_STATS . " VALUES (null, '$ip', '$Chrome', '$IE', '$Firefox', '$Opera', '$Safari', '$otherb', '$Windows', '$Mac', '$Linux', '$Android' , '$iOS' , '$otheros', 1)");
        if ($q == true){
           return(1);
        }
        else{
           return(0);
        }
    }
    else if (mysql_num_rows($q1)==1){
        extract(mysql_fetch_array($ql));
        switch($browser){
            case "Internet Explorer":
                $IE += 1;
            break;
            case "Firefox":
                $Firefox += 1;
            break;
            case "Safari":
                $Safari += 1;
            break;
            case "Opera":
                $Opera += 1;
            break;
            case "Chrome":
                $Chrome += 1;
            break;
            default:
                $otherb += 1;
            break;
        }
        switch($os){
            case "Windows":
                $Windows += 1;
            break;
            case "Mac OS X":
                $Mac += 1;
            break;
            case "Linux":
                $Linux += 1;
            break;
            case "Android":
                $Android += 1;
            break;
            case "iOS":
                $iOS += 1;
            break;
            default:
                $otheros += 1;
            break;
        }
        $totalVisits += 1;
        $q = $this->query("UPDATE " . DB_STATS . " set Chrome='$Chrome', IE='$IE', Firefox='$Firefox', Opera='$Opera', Safari='$Safari', otherb='$otherb', Windows='$Windows', Mac='$Mac', Linux='$Linux', Android='$Android' , iOS='$iOS' , otheros='$otheros', totalVisits='$totalVisits'");
        if ($q == true){
           return(1);
        }
        else{
           return(0);
        }
    }
    else{
        return(-1);
    }
}
```

I hope everything made sense and that someone will help.

Comment: You need to check errors after `mysql_query()`.  `if (!$q1) {echo mysql_error();}`

Comment: I have done that before posting and no errors appear and there is still none, I don't know why though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see it now -- you used `$ql` (lower case L) when you intend to use `$q1`.  Let this be a lesson against using very short variable names or very similar names.

```
// $ql was initialized to 0
$ql = 0; $totalVisits = 0;

// $q1 holds the result resource
extract(mysql_fetch_array($q1));
```

It is not advisable to call `extract()` on the output of `mysql_fetch_array()` unless you also specify the second parameter `MYSQL_ASSOC` as the fetch type.  By default it returns *both* numeric and associative indices for each column.

```
extract(mysql_fetch_array($q1, MYSQL_ASSOC));
// Or better
extract(mysql_fetch_assoc($q1));
```

In general, I would probably advise against using `extract()` in most any situation, since it results in numerous variables dumped into the global namespace, in particular when you have done `SELECT *` without being specific about which columns are selected.  Better to access them via their array:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q1);
echo $row['browser'];
```

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you! Notepad++ on Win7 makes 1s and ls look identical! :) Ill mark your answer as the right one as soon as I can :) And ok, I will add MYSQL_ASSOC to the mysql_fetch_array

Comment: +1. This is one good reason why a coder should use descriptive variable name (not long, but gives a clue what it is about).

Comment: Don't blame Notepad++, it's a pretty decent editor. It's your choice of font that makes 1s and ls look the same. You should probably switch to a different one. I use Anonymous Pro but if you search a little, you can find a lot of good programming fonts. Find one that looks good and helps distinguish similar characters.